# Armature Origins Wrong?

Tags: rigging, armature, origin

I feel like this question must have been answered, but I can't seem to find the answer here or on blender artists. Maybe I don't understand the issue well enough to google the right terms.

I'm having a bunch of issues with my armature origins on my flower object.

[image]

Whenever I select it, it wants to orient to the center of the blend file. I've tried resetting the origins, but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe I'm not resetting the correct object?

Also, I want to be able to rotate the flower head so that it spins like a pinwheel when I try to do this though, it rotates all random directions. How do I get it just to rotate on one axis flat with the circle in the center?

Like I said, I feel like this is probably an easy fix, but I can't seem to find the answer myself. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my blend file if that helps: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D6UcaWpicOzJZawOT6LgRAYhLhGDn0Wy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It appears in the original file that the origins were set incorrectly. Probably from an easy to make keystroke or click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Change the origins of the flower center and petals and stem by using

[origin to geometry]

as depicted in the image above.

The

- flower center
- flowers petals
- stem

should be quickly changed to have their origin modified as above or with the mesh itself or perimeter.  I see your petals have the correct parent of the flower center. Suggestion. Names of objects can be quickly improved The visual stem mesh should have a name like [stem]. The flower center should/could have the [stem] as parent, depending on animation complexity.

[image]

Above image shows more correct placement of origins.  Your can manually improve the flower petal origins if that suits your tastes.

Currently your origins are not in the correct place.

Comment: Ok, I did this but it still rotates a bit funny, not like a pinwheel. Is there any way to change the direction of the origin/axis, not just the position.

Comment: I would like you to write a bit more exactly.  What are you rotating?  Which object? If the original question has been answered or not answered I encourage you to upvote or downvote in the near future.

Comment: I do not want to stray to for from the original question.  Yet I have a suggestion.  You flower petals could be subdivided in [edit mode] and reshaped with proportional edit if you want more flowing form.

Comment: You may choose to see various episodes of this tutorial series.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lY6KPrc4uMw&list=PLda3VoSoc_TR7X7wfblBGiRz-bvhKpGkS

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer so in depth. When I center the origin points on the flower and go to rotate it, it looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/2plnCsu

Is there anyway to change the direction of it's axis so it rotates like a proper pinwheel in it's current orientation.

I appreciate the advice on naming, I plan to do that at the end before starting the big project. I'm also going for a low polygon look, so it's fine as is, but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: This seems to be  a second Blender question which is best put in a second question in Blender Stack Exchange BSE question.  Please create a new question.  Currently I do not understand the 2nd problem.  Rotate can be followed by [x] [y] [z] keystrokes to select an axis... or you can change your point of view in the 3D view before rotating.  This concepts are best explained in the video tutorial series link enclosed above.

Comment: Neither up vote or down vote has been selected.

Comment: Please try rotating [edit] mode or [object] mode if that helps.

Comment: I needed to rotate the object in edit mode, to where I wanted it, then reset all my origins. This solved my issue. Thank you.